# Hamiltonian as a quadratic function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I’m reading R.K Pathria’s *Statistical Mechanics*, third edition, and I'm having trouble understanding eq. (8) in section 3.7.

It goes like this:

In many physical situations the Hamiltonian of the system happens to be a quadratic function of its coordinates; so, through a canonical transformation, it can be brought into the form

$$ H= \sum_j A_j P_j^2 + \sum_j B_j Q_j^2 $$

where $P_j$ and $Q_j$ are the transformed, canonically conjugate, coordinates while $A_j$ and $B_j$ are certain constants of the problem. For such a system, "we clearly have"
$$
\sum_j \left( P_j \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}+ Q_j \frac{\partial H}{\partial Q_j}\right) = 2H.
$$

I don’t get this last equation. How can see that it is true for this system?

Comment: What do you get when you calculate $\partial H/\partial P_j$?  Or $\partial H/\partial Q_j$?

Comment: $$ \dot{Q_j} =\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}$$  and $$ \dot{P_j} =\frac{\partial H}{\partial Q_j}$$ right? what i'm i not seeing here?

Comment: No, not right. What you have written in your comment above are just the generic Hamiltonian equations of motion. You need to calculate the actual value of $\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}$ in terms of $P$ and $Q$ given your specific expression for $H$, which is $\sum_i \left(A_i P_i^2 + B_i Q_i^2\right)$

Answer (score 3):

> $$ H= \sum_j A_j P_j^2 + \sum_j B_j Q_j^2 $$

> For such a system, "we clearly have"
> $$ \sum_j \left( P_j \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}+ Q_j \frac{\partial H}{\partial Q_j}\right) = 2H.  $$

> I don’t get this last equation. How can see that it is true for this system?

You were asked in the comments to calculate $\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}$ and you responded by writing:

> $\dot Q_j = \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}$

This is not what you were asked to calculate. What you wrote in the quote above is one of the Hamiltonian equations or motion, which holds generally for any $H$.

For your specific $H$, which is
$$
H = \sum_j A_j P_j^2 + \sum_j B_j Q_j^2\;, \tag{1}
$$
you want to treat $H$ as a function of $P$ and $Q$, a function which is *literally* written in Eq. (1) above, and *take the partial derivative of the right-hand side of Eq. (1) with respect to $P_j$*.

As an example, I will show you how to take the derivative with respect to $P_1$. But, that's it. I'm not doing *all* your homework for you.

The derivative of the right-hand-side of Eq. (1) with respect to $P_1$ is:
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_1} 
=\frac{\partial}{\partial P_1}\left(A_1 P_1^2 + A_2 P_2^2 + A_3 P_3^2+\ldots\right)
= 2 A_1 P_1
$$

I hope you can take it from here.